# JavaFX Returning Correct Data From One Controller to Another

Tags: java, javafx

I have two controllers. One controller manages most of the main functionality, the other controls a simple pop up prompt, accessed from the main controller.

This is the function stored in the main controller, used to access the prompt.

```
public void deletePrompt(){
    DeletePromptController controller = new DeletePromptController();
    boolean result = controller.showPrompt("/MainWindow//DeletePrompt.fxml");
    if(result){
        System.out.println("Deleted");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Canceled");
    }
}
```

This is the prompt controller

```
public class DeletePromptController extends ShowWindow {
    public Label question;
    public Button delete, cancel;
    private boolean result = true;

    boolean showPrompt(String path){
        showWindow(path);
        return result;
    }

    public void delete(){
        System.out.println("D");
        result = true;
        Stage stage = (Stage) delete.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    public void cancel(){
        System.out.println("C");
        result = false;
        Stage stage = (Stage) cancel.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

And this is the block used to load and show the delete prompt fxml file.

```
public class ShowWindow {
    public void showWindow(String path){
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
            Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working except one thing. The main controller when getting the result from the prompt controller is not getting the correct Boolean result.

Output when delete is pressed:

```
D
Canceled
```

Output when cancel is pressed:

```
C
Canceled
```

D should be followed by Deleted.

Anything helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FXMLLoader` creates a new controller instance, since the `fx:controller` attribute is provided in the fxml.

You've basically got 2 options:

1. Remove the `fx:controller` attribute from the fxml and specify the controller yourself:

   ```
   public void showWindow(String path){
       try {
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(path));
           fxmlLoader.setController(this);
           Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
   ```

   or
2. Get the controller created by the `FXMLLoader`

   ```
   public static <T> T showWindow(String path){
       try {
           FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(ShowWindow.class.getResource(path));
           Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
           Stage stage = new Stage();
           stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
           stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
           stage.showAndWait();
           return fxmlLoader.getController();
       }catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   ```
   boolean showPrompt(String path) {
       return ShowWindow.<DeletePromptController>showWindow(path).result;
   }
   ```

Comment: @Leon: Whoops. Of course that needs to be changed in a static method. Should be fixed now...